# How to append data of multiple files into single file?

Tags: shell, text-processing

For example:
I have `01.txt` and `02.txt` files and need to append data of these files into new file `new.txt`.

It should append data based on `01.txt` followed by `02.txt` files.

Before this I have to delete only the first AND last line of the files( `01.txt` `02.txt` ) and then append them into the new file.

How Do we accomplish this using UNIX?

Answer (score 6):

Another approach:

```
for file in 01.txt 02.txt; do sed '1d;$d;' "$f"; done > output
```

This is particularly useful if there are many files you need to concatenate:

```
for file in *.txt; do ...
```

You can also use shell expansion:

```
for file in 0{1,2}.txt; do ...
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy way of printing all except the first line of a file is [`tail`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/tail):

```
tail -n +2 01.txt
```

To print all but the last line of a file, use [`head`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/head):

```
head -n -1 01.txt
```

So, to put all this together and print all but the first and last lines of `01.txt` and `02.txt` and save them as `03.txt`, you can use a [subshell](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/subshells.html) to combine the output of the above commands on the two files:

```
(tail -n +2 01.txt | head -n -1; tail -n +2 02.txt | head -n -1) > new.txt
```

Comment: That requires GNU `head`. `head -n -1` is not standard.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas which part? The `-n` [seems](http://www.unix.com/man-page/POSIX/1/head/) to be standard, is it the `-` format that is not?

Comment: See the [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/head.html), only positive integer numbers are supported.

Answer (score 4):

You could delete the first and last line with sed:

```
sed -e '1d' -e '$d' file1 > output
sed -e '1d' -e '$d' file2 >> output
sed -e '1d' -e '$d' file3 >> output
```

Answer (score 1):

With a for loop, head and tail:

```
for f in 01.txt 02.txt; do head -n-1 $f | tail -n+2; done > newfile.txt
```

With python:

```
python -c 'print("\n".join(["\n".join(open(f).read()[:-1].split("\n")[1:-1]) for f in ("01.txt", "02.txt")]))' > newfile.txt
```

Or with awk:

```
awk 'FNR > 1 { lines[FILENAME][FNR] = $0; lines[FILENAME][0] = FNR } END { for (i=1; i < ARGC; i++) { for (i2=2; i2 < lines[ARGV[i]][0]; i2++) { print lines[ARGV[i]][i2]; } } }' 01.txt 02.txt > newfile.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

With GNU `sed`:

```
sed -s '1d;$d' ./*.txt > output
```

Note: you want to make sure the name of the output file doesn't match the globbing pattern (`*.txt` above). Otherwise, you'd have to write it like:

```
sed -sn '1d;$d;w output.txt' ./*.txt
```

(assuming `output.txt` didn't exist beforehand).

Answer (score -2):

```
sed \$r01.txt new.txt
sed \$r02.txt new.txt
```

Comment: Can you explain how this would function, with some input examples and output?